# Is there a way to force Node.js to print the source / trace of all console logs?

Tags: node.js

I'm running code that should not be executing anything Tensorflow related, but when I kill the process with ^C, I get the following logs as it dies:

```
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
```

As a cybersecurity professional, I'm concerned / wondering if perhaps one of the packages I've installed is compromised or 'typosquatted' and using my CPU for crypto mining or worse. Perhaps that's far-fetched, but nevertheless I'd like to figure out what is generating these logs, like a stack trace.

### What I've tried:

I'm using Chrome's devtools (which helpfully links the source of all console logs) to attach to the Node.js process, but these logs aren't rendered there. When I Google this, I don't get much useful / relevant info.

Any way to force sort of a stack trace for all Node.js logs?

Comment: You can override `console.log` with your function. ```const old_console_log = console.log;
console.log = (...args) => { console.trace(); old_console_log(...args); };
```
This code should be placed at the very beginning of your index file (before importing libs).

Comment: @bogdanoff oh very good idea, I didn't think of overriding. I'll try this also with things like console.warn.